# Проводник не открывает внешний жесткий диск

Tags: windows, hdd

Всем привет. Сегодня утром я включил свой ноут и подключил к нему свой внешний жесткий диск от Toshiba на 1ТБ и он отображается в проводнике как "Локальный диск" (вместо "Khudoyorov") без указания объема, когда пытаюсь открыть его, то проводник перезагружается и вижу фиолетовый экран (избавиться помогает принудительное выключение). Подключил к разным компам но результат все тот же, заменил кабель на другой не помогло. Решил посмотреть в диспетчере задач проц просто так нагружается на 30%, а раздел управления дисками не загружается. Подключил к разъему USB 2.0/3.0/3.1 Gen1 результат все тот же. Если есть решение, то желательно без форматирования. ОС у меня вин 10 про х64. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь!!!

Comment: [Вот ссылка на скриншот](http://khisrav.000webhostapp.com/images/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9.jpg)

Comment: Диск на свалку. Форматировать не требуется.

Comment: Если нужно спасти данные, то следует обратиться в специализированную организацию, которая занимается восстановлением данных с битых дисков. (будет дорого). Можно попробовать вытащить диск из бокса и подключить напрямую, чтобы попытаться спасти данные. В дальнейшем использование этого диска категорически не рекомендуется.

Comment: Добавлю, что было бы неплохо его проверить на стационарном компе (вытащив из бокса как советовали выше) через `mhdd`.

Comment: А чем может быть вызвано такое состояние накопителя?